# How do I combine 3 separate lists into 1 list with 3 columns or fields?

Tags: c#, list, class, foreach

How do I combine 3 separate lists into one list with 3 columns or fields in c#?

I tried using 3 foreach loops to add/combine the 3 separate lists to each column or field into one list but it only adds them one column/field at a time and the list is 3 times as long as I need it to be and only has one column/field of data while the other two columns/fields are null or zero. Like this:

```
0 0 3.701

0 0 3.633

0 0 3.622

0 0 3.623
```

I need it to be like:

```
12 2020 3.623
```

Here is my code.

```
        List<GasPrices> listOfGasPrices = new List<GasPrices>()
        {
        new GasPrices() { Month = 11, Year = 1942, Price = 3.333 }

        };

        foreach (var month in intMonthList)
        {
            listOfGasPrices.Add(new GasPrices { Month = month }); 
            
        }

        foreach (var year in intYearList)
        {
            listOfGasPrices.Add(new GasPrices { Year = year });

        }

        foreach (var price in doublePriceList)
        {
            listOfGasPrices.Add(new GasPrices { Price = price });
        }

        for (int k = 0; k < listOfGasPrices.Count; k++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(listOfGasPrices[k].Month + " " + listOfGasPrices[k].Year + " " + listOfGasPrices[k].Price);
        }
    


class GasPrices
{
    //backing fields
    private int _month, _year;
    private double _price;

    //constructor
    public GasPrices()
    {
        _month=0;
        _year=0;
        _price=0;
    }

    //getter and setters of properties
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using three foreach loops that way, use the following code

```
List<int> intMonthList = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 }; // Taking sample values
List<int> intYearList = new List<int>() { 2019, 2020, 2021 };
List<double> doublePriceList = new List<double>() { 7.1, 8.2, 9.3 };

List<GasPrices> listOfGasPrices = new List<GasPrices>()
{
    new GasPrices() { Month = 11, Year = 1942, Price = 3.333 }

};

using(var month = intMonthList.GetEnumerator())
using(var year = intYearList.GetEnumerator())
using(var price = doublePriceList.GetEnumerator())
{
    while(month.MoveNext() && year.MoveNext() && price.MoveNext())
    {
        listOfGasPrices.Add(new GasPrices { Month = month.Current, Year = year.Current, Price = price.Current });

    }
}

for (int k = 0; k < listOfGasPrices.Count; k++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(listOfGasPrices[k].Month + " " + listOfGasPrices[k].Year + " " + listOfGasPrices[k].Price);
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution, but you might want to update your solution such that loop runs for all 12 months for every given year.

Comment: As far as I understood from his question that he just wanted to combine the answer of 3 separate lists into one list so I did that, I don't know if he particularly needs the solution for all 12 months in a given year. If he needs that then your answer with nested foreach loop will do it

Comment: That's a good point too. We are not sure how the lists are configured, so hard to add a precise solution.

Comment: All 3 lists are 1065 items/lines long with intMonthList ranging 1-12, intYearList 1993-2013, and doublePriceList .900-3.999       Thank you in advance. I will try these soon =)

Comment: Thank you both! @malik_aurko96's code is exactly what I needed =)

Comment: Please mark it as an answer if it worked for you. Also, edit your question to add more details on how your lists are configured.

Answer (score 0):

Please add more details on how your month, year, and price lists are configured.

- Assuming intYearList have a year range: for e.g. 1950-2020
- Assuming intMonthList have 12 months, i.e. 1-12
- Assuming doublePriceList is a flat series.

  ```
   int yearIndex = 0;        

   foreach(var year in intYearList)
   {
      int monthIndex = 0;
      foreach(var month in intMonthList)
      { 
        var priceIndex = yearIndex*12 + monthIndex;
        var price = doublePriceList[priceIndex];

        listOfGasPrices.Add(new GasPrices { Month = month, Year = year, Price = price });

        monthIndex++;

      }

       yearIndex++;

    }
  ```